# Running python code in Visual Studio code?

Tags: python

Please do not close this question. It's so hard to get started. I wanted to learn to program, I followed a python tutorial that used VS Code as the IDE.

```
          def main():
           print("hello wrld")
          main()
```

He wrote the above code and in VS Code clicked on the debug icon, this icon can not be seen on my version of vs code, it shows an icon called Run. When I go to the top menu and click on Run, then start debugging, it open the chrome browser instead of running my code. Why does it open chrome?

Comment: VC Code can be used as an IDE for many languages - you should probably find and go through a tutorial on how to set up VS Code for Python before continuing. It doesn't just work for any language without setup. If you don't want to spend time on setting up an IDE for the language, consider using an IDE that's specific to Python, like PyCharm or Spyder.

Comment: Have you consulted the VSCode documentation?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to extensions and download the python compiler. Then make sure your file is of .py extension then a run symbol should come up and run in the console